# remote socket listener

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a question.
I would like to create a socket listener, but the listen address is from a remote server.

So say SERVER A has the socket listener.
SERVER B (ex. IP = 123.456.78.23:1970) has the listen port.

If I create the socket like this (and execute it on server A):

```
IP EndPoint endpointIp = new IPEndPoint(123.456.78.23, 1970);
this._socket = new Socket(endpointIp.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
this._socket.Bind(endpointIp); // crashes here
this._socket.Listen(MaxPendingConnections);
```

The program crashes on the Bind code: "The requested address is not valid in its context".

How can I listen on a remote port?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't listen to ports on another server. You probably want to connect to a server on a specific port using a socket. Is that what you need/want?

Comment: Hello, here is my setup. I have 2 servers (using biztalk), they work like a failover setup, if 1 server goes down the other takes over. I don't know if you are familiar with biztalk, but it goes like this: the 2 servers are connected with biztalk, inside biztalk I have a 'listener' that listens to a port. Now the 2 servers have each a different IP address, so if 1 server goes down, the other one can't take over because it is listening to an IP that doesn't exist anymore.. So I thought I would listen to an IP address that isn't linked to the servers, but this isn't possible apparently..

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is a subset of load balancing. This will require a load balancer - either a router or another server (with a special application) that will sit in front of servers A and B.

Answer (score 1):

You can't listen to a port on one computer from another.  (Hence the message "not valid in this context")

What you CAN do is write one program/service that runs on SERVER B and listens to the port, and use Remoting or WCF to write ANOTHER program that runs on SERVER A that monitors *your service* on SERVER B rather than trying to listen on a *port* on SERVER B.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a socket using an `IPEndPoint` (basically IP and port) of a different server. What you are asking about is server spoofing - pretending to be a different server and receiving the traffic addressed to it. You will need to configure server A to have the IP of server B, and make sure every router on the way to it can reach server A with this IP.

**Edit:** Following your comment on the original question, what you need is a load balancer. In order to allow for server B to take over when server A is dead, you must have a router or a server that receives all traffic and directs it to server A, then if it senses that server A is down will redirect all traffic to server B. Of course since you already are doing load balancing, might as well make it a real load balancer, forwarding the traffic to both servers while both are up, and to the remaining one when the other one fails.

Comment: And is it possible with a "virtual IP address" or something like that? I think if I assign the same IP address to both servers that I will have some network issues..

Comment: I've read your comment on the original question and updated the answer.